# How do I apply no signaling condition for the given Quantum Adder problem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-computer

The Unitary transformation for the Imperfect Quantum Adder problem is such:

[image]

Both the states belong to two Hilbert Spaces and we are trying to add both states to one system using Ancillary qubit.

I am trying to think in the direction of the  [Quantum Cloning without Signaling by N.Gisin](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9801005) for the No Signaling approach. Can I use the generic approach here? Can someone help me regarding the mathematics of no signaling and how one applies it depending on the problem?

Comment: what do you mean by "applying the no-signaling condition" to this problem?

Comment: I just want to find the maximum fidelity of the Quantum Adder using No Signaling criteria, just like it is done for the Cloning problem.

Comment: fidelity between what and what? (also, remember to tag people with @theirName in a comment, or they won't be notified of your answer)

Comment: @glS The fidelity between the state formed by perfect addition (if the Adder was perfect) and the actual resultant state that we get (addition by an Imperfect Quantum Adder) . Cause Perfect Quantum Adder is not possible. Just like perfect Cloning is not possible so we use No Signaling criterion for finding out the fidelity between the perfect cloning and maximum cloning we can achieve.